# How to mock a module export function

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, sinon

I have a function that is exported like this:

```
// myFunc.js
....
....
module.exports = myFunc;
```

And then in another file I have:

```
// main.js
const myFunc = require('../../myFunc');
...
...
myFunc.then( .... )
```

How can I mock `myFunc` in `myFunc.js` with another function?
I've tried:

```js
sinon.stub(myFuncFilePath).callsFake(myOtherFuncFilePath);
```

But it's not working, apparently because of the way `myFunc` is exported.
I **can't** change the way it is exported in `myFunc.js`, so how else can I mock it?

Answer (score 0):

sinon doesn't support stub a function directly. You need use [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to rewire the module:

E.g.
`myFunc.js`:

```js
async function myFunc() {
  console.log('myFunc');
}

module.exports = myFunc;
```

`main.js`:

```js
const myFunc = require('./myFunc');

function main() {
  return myFunc().then(res => console.log(res));
}

module.exports = main;
```

`main.spec.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('main', () => {
  it('should stub myFunc', async () => {
    const myFuncStub = sinon.stub().resolves('fake data');
    const main = proxyquire('./main', {
      './myFunc.js': myFuncStub
    });
    const logSpy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');
    const actual = await main();
    expect(actual).to.be.undefined;
    expect(myFuncStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    expect(logSpy.calledWith('fake data')).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
  main
fake data
    ✓ should stub myFunc (44ms)


  1 passing (49ms)

--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File          |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files     |    94.44 |      100 |       80 |    94.12 |                   |
 main.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 main.spec.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 myFunc.js    |       50 |      100 |        0 |       50 |                 2 |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57013728